# Websphere application server network deployment trial for Windows XP platform

Tags: websphere

I could not locate link for downloading trial edition of "Websphere application server network deployment for Windows XP platform". either 6.x version or 7.x version? I need it urgent for self-learning purpose.

The only link I could find is :- 
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/downloads/ws/wasnd/?S_TACT=105AGX28&S_CMP=TRIALS

It seems to support only Linux.

Any pointers will highly be appreciated. If someone has local copy, please share.

---

I have kept this question for so long to someone to provide inputs. Thanks all of above for your responses. I guess I will have to just wait for licensed version of WAS ND 6.x/7.x to get going. It should be available once the project is started. Thanks all.

Comment: can anyone explain how can I practice WAS network deployment features on my windows machine as I am not able to locate WAS ND evaluation copy for windows..

Comment: Sorry you wanted 7, that was 8.

Comment: According to [this post](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=14439939&#14439939) there is no trial.

WAS ND 8 Trial does support windows, here is the link: [WAS ND Trial](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/downloads/ws/wasnetwork/) . What are you trying to get more familiar with clustering or WAS itself?

Comment: @Terrell, well I am expecting a project to be worked which is using WAS ND 7.x and/or 6.x. So I am training myself.

Comment: @Terrell, I am very aware of WAS in standalone server mode. When it comes to multiple instances of WAS: so SIB clustering, load balancing & HA manager, these are concepts only theoretical in my mind, no practical experience.

Comment: Given that the [Features for ND 8](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/webservers/appserv/was/network/features/) are still the same as WAS7. If you want to familiarize yourself with clustering that may be the way to go.

Answer (score -1):

You are looking for [WebSphere Application Server for Developers](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/downloads/ws/wasdevelopers/index.html).  Use the link under [Previous versions](https://www14.software.ibm.com/webapp/iwm/web/preLogin.do?lang=en_US&source=swg-wsasfd&S_CMP=web_dw_rt_swd) on that page to download 7.0 or 6.1.

Comment: My apologies, I was under the mistaken impression that WAS for developers included ND capabilities.  I downloaded it now and verified that it does not.